# how to fix upgrading prestashop with 1clickupgrade error message

Tags: prestashop-1.7

This is the error message i get when trying to upgrade prestashop version "Could not close the Zip file: /home3/rbwyygmy/public_html/admin355ryeyla/autoupgrade/backup/auto-backupfiles_V1.7.4.3_20240222-190759-113d6124.zip properly. Check you are allowed to write on the disk and there is available space on it."

can you provide me solution for this error